# Calculating the posterior distribution in multivariate Gaussian processes

Tags: statistics, matlab

Matlab profiler throws this horrible bottleneck which is called 700000 times:

```
for k =1:model.nlf,
    for r =1:model.nlf,
        KuyDinvKyu = zeros(model.k,model.k);
        for q =1:model.nout,
            KuyDinvKyu = KuyDinvKyu + model.KuyDinv{k,q}*model.Kyu{q,r};
        end
        if (k == r)
            model.A{k,r} = model.Kuu{k} + KuyDinvKyu;
        else
            model.A{k,r} = KuyDinvKyu;
        end
    end
end
```

Even if the math is correct, there must be a faster way.

Comment: some dimensions and sizes can be useful here. What are `size(model.KuyDinv{k,q})`, `size(model.Kyu{q,r})` and `size(model.Kuu{k})`?

Comment: I also think that a bit of intuition into what this code is trying to compute (very high level motivation) can be of assistance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that all variables are cells?

Comment: As above; this questions is impossible to answer without knowing the dimensions of model.KuyDinv{k,q}.  Are these vectors?  Scalars?

Comment: concerning dimensions model.nlf is number of latent forces: up to 20 lf; nout is number of outputs also up to 20.

Comment: what this is doing: calculating the posterior distribution in multivariate Gaussian Processes

Comment: Why cell arrays? They all seem to be of the same size, so why not store it in a multi-dimensional matrix instead?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `model.KuyDinv{k,q}` and `model.Kyu{q,r}` are a matrices (as the name would imply), there is little you can do. You can move the initialization of `KuyDinvKyu` outside the loop, and eliminate the branch to compute the diagonals:

```
% define it once -- saves many calls to 'zeros'
KuyDinvKyu_0 = zeros(model.k);

for k = 1:model.nlf
    for r = 1:model.nlf

        KuyDinvKyu = KuyDinvKyu_0;

        for q = 1:model.nout
            KuyDinvKyu = KuyDinvKyu + model.KuyDinv{k,q}*model.Kyu{q,r};
        end

        % removed IF      
        model.A{k,r} = KuyDinvKyu;

    end
end

% without IF
for c = 1:model.nlf    
    model.A{c,c} = model.A{c,c} + model.Kuu{c};    
end
```

If `model.KuyDinv{k,q}` and/or `model.Kyu{q,r}` contain *scalars*, well then we can optimize this much further for sure. So I need to know the size and type of data that `model.Kyu{q,r}` and  `model.KuyDinv{k,q}` will contain.

It might also be that your overall data design (e.g., the choice to use `cells`) is flawed and causes inefficiencies. So it could also be helpful to see some more surrounding code, so I can determine if there is some improvement to be made in that respect.

Comment: Thanks Rody for this very helpful reply. I implemented your solution and improved the profiler color code for that loop from red to pink. model.KuyDinv and all the others are matrices. I inherited this routine and I would agree that the overall data design using cells is the problem.

Comment: @user2015897: I think you suggested an edit to my answer, that got rejected -- you should indeed post this as part of the *question* (rather than my *answer*), so that not only I but everyone here can take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

You will get a speed up by eliminating the if-statements in the inner loop. E.g. by splitting the inner loop via

```
    for r = setdiff(1:model.nlf,k)
        %do the stuff to setup Model.A{k,r}
    end

    model.A{k,k} = ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It has been confirmed and implemented with the second answer below. The profiler has improved from red to pink, a step in the right direction. Many thanks for your help